# Comparison of one element in array to all other elements in same array

Tags: c, arrays, loops, compare

I understand that we can compare each element of the array with every other in this manner:

```
    for (f = 0; f < length2; f++) {
    for (p = f + 1; p < length2 ; p++) {
        if(!(compareThem(split[f],split[p]) == 1) && (split[f] != 0) && (split[p] != 0)) {
            no_of_unique++;
        }
    }
}
```

However, I only want no_of_unique to increase after checking the element of index f with ALL the element of index p. This, however, checks the element f with p= f + 1, increases no_of_unique, then checks the other elements and increases it for each case. I only need it to increase after its checked ALL of the elements. Any help would be appreciated.

P.S The compareThem function basically just returns 1 if they are equal to one another.

Comment: What happens if you add a break-statement after you increment no_of_unique?

Comment: @Rusab-- please correct me if I am wrong, but I think that you are asking about finding the number of unique elements in an array. But, the way you have phrased this makes it sound like you only want the number of elements not followed by copies of themselves. This seem less useful to me, but maybe that is what you are after. Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of incrementing **no_of_unique** within the scope of the inner loop, you may simply break after finding an element that is equal to **split[f]**. Then, outside the inner loop, you should check whether **p** is equal to **length2**, which would mean that the inner loop did not break and traversed all the elements till the end of the array. (i.e. did not encounter an element equal to **split[f]**)

```
for (f = 0; f < length2; f++) {
    if (split[f] != 0) {
        for (p = 0; p < length2 ; p++) {
            if( f != p && (split[p] != 0) && (compareThem(split[f],split[p]) == 1)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (p == length2) {
            no_of_unique++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to set `foundUnique` to `1` in the first loop.

Comment: @ilim-- your algorithm counts later elements in the array as unique whether or not they have already been found.

Comment: @DavidBowling You are correct. The sample code OP provided was comparing it not with *all* elements, but rather *the rest* of the array. I fixed my code to work for the case you mentioned as well.

Comment: @DavidBowling [here](http://ideone.com/cEzik9) is a sample usage of the code I provided with the correct output.

Comment: @DavidBowling no worries. Feel free to upvote id you think the answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I am reading your question, given that the title is "Comparison of one element to *all* other elements in same array," you want to find the number of unique elements in an array. For each element in the array, you must find whether there are duplicates following it, but also preceding it. Here is a solution that does this. I used character arrays in my example, but you could easily adapt this to other types. The `countUnique()` function does the forward search for duplicates, and when it finds a potential unique element, the `alreadyFound()` function checks the preceding elements.:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int countUnique(char arr[], int n);
int compareThem(char c1, char c2);
int alreadyFound(char c, char list[], int n);

int main(void)
{
    char test1[] = "abcababdb";
    int s_len = strlen(test1);

    printf("test1: %d unique elements\n", countUnique(test1, s_len));

    return 0;
}
int countUnique(char arr[], int n)
{
    int no_of_unique = 0;
    int f, p;

    for (f = 0; f < n; f++) {
        for (p = f + 1; p < n; p++) {
            if(compareThem(arr[f],arr[p]) == 1)
                break;
        }
        if (p == n && !alreadyFound(arr[f], arr, f)) {
            no_of_unique++;
        }
    }

    return no_of_unique;
}

int compareThem(char c1, char c2)
{
    if (c2 - c1)
        return 0;
    return 1;
}

int alreadyFound(char c, char list[], int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (c == list[i])
            return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```